# Серверный рендеринг React + Django

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

Доброго времени суток, пишу SPA, используя Реакт и Джанго, подружил которые друг с другом с помощью webpack-django-loader и Django REST Framework - Джанго передает данные по API и обработанный webpack джаваскрипт-файл эти самые данные принимает с помощью следующего кода:

```js
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/main');
        const MainPage = await res.json();
        this.setState({MainPage})
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Естественно, что рендеринг данных происходит на клиентской стороне.
Вопрос в том, как организовать серверный рендерниг Реакт+ Джанго и какие есть подходы а так же best practices?

Comment: Бест практис будет изоморфное приложение на реакт + node js. Нода будет ходит по api в django бэк. Появится возможность рендерить на сервере те же самые реакт шалблоны.
Если это не подходит, то рендерить на сервере с помощью jinja например, а уже потом подключать реакт, получится небольшое дублирование шаблонов, но это выход если вы не хотите использовать node js

Comment: Можно отдельно запустить Django сервер для апи и отдельно Express для реакт приложения. В этом курсе хорошо все объясняют https://www.udemy.com/server-side-rendering-with-react-and-redux/